# Get Number of a Dynamic Width Element

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to have the width in Numbers( without Px ) of a Dynamic Width Element ( width: auto ), I tried it with clientWidth, parseInt, offsetWidth, but it always returned with a '0' or with NaN.

How can I have that numbers?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jquery

```
 alert($("#mydiv").innerWidth().replace("px",""));
```

in javascript

```
alert (document.getElementById('mydiv').style.width.replace("px",""));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can I have it in a Variable, I want to Apply some Javascript on they, anyway, thanks a lot again!

Comment: sure `var mywidth = $("#mydiv").innerWidth().replace("px","");`

Comment: Hmm, I'm tring to use it but it isnt get right, could you take a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cMZuN/1/ ? Thanks a lot again

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto just use `$("#mydiv").width()`

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto `.innerWidth()` returns a number not a string http://jsfiddle.net/cMZuN/2/

Comment: WOW, EPIC, thanks a lot, Is there a Way for reward you? Thanks a lot again!